# Pop up type message avoiding script in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, popup, message

I have created a popup help message using Toast in script.

Unfortunately, the first time script warning messages that Google presents to users of my Sheet, will confuse or put them off continuing. I have many users. I do not have their log in details.

**Is there a way of having a popup type message WITHOUT using Script?**

My boring backup plan is just to have a link to a help tab, but a pop up type window would be better ... Alternatively, is there a way of getting round the script warning messages?

Thanks for your help. Newman

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> Is there a way of having a popup type message WITHOUT using Script?

No. An alternative to show pop up messages is to have a range set to display messages. You might use this together with conditional formatting to visually tell the user that they should look to the messages range.

> Alternatively, is there a way of getting round the script warning messages?

No, but you might use installable triggers in order to execute the scripts as you instead of your spreadsheet users, i.e. you could use a on edit trigger together with cell checkboxes instead of using a custom menu to call functions that require authorization to run.

Comment: Can you tell me a bit more about installable triggers. Which do you think might be effective? Currently the pop up help script launches when an image is clicked.